# Is there a way to hide all shared links pointing to a certain domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

People are spamming what-character-are-you.com like crazy since a few weeks. It's extremely annoying and I'd like to hide those posts for good. Unfortunately they are not posted via an app but just shared links so I can't just block the app.

Is there any way to block link posts pointing to a certain domain on Facebook or do I really need to write my own userscript for it (and then still see that crap on mobile)?